# QlistWidget won't show in a custom QFrame

Tags: python, pyqt6

I can't get `ModMergeFrame` frame to show the `self.mod_list`. I have tried reading the docs and examples, but failed to understand and fix the problem.

Below code in `ModMergeFrame` class works correcty. Displaying the `self.mod_list.count()` returns 2, as expected. So the list item is being created and populated. The two `QPushButtons` are visible as well, but the `QListWidget` is not.

Putting the same object in the `centralwidget` of `MainWindow` displayes it correctly though

```
class CommonFrame(QFrame):
    """ Common frame that will be used as a base for all other frames """
    def __init__(self, parent, settings, objectName):
        super().__init__(parent, objectName=objectName)
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.hide()
        self.settings = settings

class ModMergeFrame(CommonFrame):
    """ Mod merge frame that will be displayed in the main application window """
    def __init__(self, parent, settings):
        super().__init__(parent, settings, objectName="Mod merge")
        test_button = QPushButton(self.objectName(), self)
        self.layout().addWidget(test_button)

        test_button = QPushButton("13", self)
        self.layout().addWidget(test_button)

        # Mod list for selection of mods to merge
        self.mod_list = QListWidget(self)
        self.mod_list.additems(["bla", "bla2"])
        self.layout().addWidget(self.mod_list)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    """ Main application window """
    def __init__(self, settings):
        try:
            QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            self.settings = settings

            self.setMinimumSize(QSize(700, 700))
            self.setWindowTitle("Bla")

            toolbar = QToolBar("Main toolbar")
            self.addToolBar(toolbar)

            central_widget = QWidget(self)
            central_widget_layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)


            # Generate frames. Those come from custom QFrame-based classes
            # Can be toggled with toolbar and are displayed in the central widget
            self.generate_mod_merge_frame(central_widget_layout, toolbar)

            central_widget.setLayout(central_widget_layout)
            self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        except Exception as exc:
            traceback_formatted = traceback.format_exc()
            logger.info(traceback_formatted)
            raise RuntimeError(traceback_formatted) from exc

    def generate_mod_merge_frame(self, central_widget_layout, toolbar):
        """ Generates main window frame with a given name """
        frame_name = "Mod merge"
        frame = ModMergeFrame(self, self.settings)

        frame_action = QAction(frame_name, self)
        frame_action.setStatusTip(frame_name)
        frame_action.triggered.connect(
            lambda checked, frame_name=frame_name: self.show_frame_by_name(frame_name)
        )

        central_widget_layout.addWidget(frame)
        toolbar.addAction(frame_action)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please explain better what's wrong?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import * 


class CommonFrame(QFrame):
    """ Common frame that will be used as a base for all other frames """
    def __init__(self, parent, settings, objectName):
        super().__init__(parent, objectName=objectName)
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(layout)
# ?        self.hide()                                                   # ???
        self.settings = settings                                         # ?


class ModMergeFrame(CommonFrame):
    """ Mod merge frame that will be displayed in the main application window """
    def __init__(self, parent, settings):
        super().__init__(parent, settings, objectName="Mod merge")
        test_button = QPushButton(self.objectName(), self)
        self.layout().addWidget(test_button)

        test_button = QPushButton("13", self)
        self.layout().addWidget(test_button)

        # Mod list for selection of mods to merge
        self.mod_list = QListWidget(self)
        
#        self.mod_list.additems(["bla", "bla2"])                          # - additems
        self.mod_list.addItems(["bla", "bla2"])                           # + addItems
        
        self.layout().addWidget(self.mod_list)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    """ Main application window """
    def __init__(self, settings=42):                                   # ??? settings
        try:
            QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            self.settings = settings

# ?            self.setMinimumSize(QSize(600, 600))
            self.setWindowTitle("Bla")

            toolbar = QToolBar("Main toolbar")
            self.addToolBar(toolbar)

            central_widget = QWidget(self)
            central_widget_layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)

            # Generate frames. Those come from custom QFrame-based classes
            # Can be toggled with toolbar and are displayed in the central widget
            self.generate_mod_merge_frame(central_widget_layout, toolbar)

            central_widget.setLayout(central_widget_layout)
            self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        except Exception as exc:
            traceback_formatted = traceback.format_exc()
            logger.info(traceback_formatted)
            raise RuntimeError(traceback_formatted) from exc

    def generate_mod_merge_frame(self, central_widget_layout, toolbar):
        """ Generates main window frame with a given name """
        frame_name = "Mod merge"
        frame = ModMergeFrame(self, self.settings)

        frame_action = QAction(frame_name, self)
        frame_action.setStatusTip(frame_name)
        frame_action.triggered.connect(          # vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv ??? <----
            lambda checked, frame_name=frame_name: self.show_frame_by_name(frame_name)
        )

        central_widget_layout.addWidget(frame)
        toolbar.addAction(frame_action)
        
    def show_frame_by_name(self, frame_name):                              # +++
        print(f'{self}') 
        print(f'{frame_name}\n') #
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image]

Comment: The problem was in fact in the method I decided not to include here as insignificant. show_frame_by_name executed hide on the `QListWidget`. It executed findChildren on main window looking for QFrame. It turns out `QListWidget` inherits from `QFrame`. Thank you for help.

Comment: @Zloj We cannot help you if you don't provide the necessary code. While this answer indirectly helped you, the issue, by your own admission, was caused by some code you never exposed in your question. For future reference, always ensure that we're given all necessary elements required to properly understand the problem so that we can provide valid and correctly related answers; in most cases, this means that you need to provide a reliable [mre]. If we cannot *reproduce* your code (and problem) accurately, we can only make assumptions, and those are often unreliable and unhelpful.

Comment: @Zloj Also, QListWidget *does* inherit from QFrame, but reality is that its inheritance is much longer. Most Qt objects have long "inheritance steps", and item views are among the most complex. It's important to always check the *full* inheritance tree of all classes you're using: not only for "basic" and indirect functions like `findChildren`, but also for proper API knowledge of *all* class capabilities. For instance, if you use QListWidget, you should **always** check its **whole** inheritance: QListWidget » QListView » QAbstractItemView » QAbstractScrollArea » QFrame » QWidget » QObject.